# Find $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\frac{an}{\log n}\left(1-\left(1-\frac{1}{an}\right)^{\log n}\right)$

Tags: calculus

I would like to solve
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\frac{an}{\log n}\left(1-\left(1-\frac{1}{an}\right)^{\log n}\right)$$
to prove that $1-\left(1-\frac{1}{an}\right)^{\log n}$ is asymptotically equivalent to $\frac{\log n}{an}$.
In fact [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5Clim_%7Bn%5Crightarrow%20%5Cinfty%7D%20%5Cfrac%7Ban%7D%7B%5Clog%20n%7D%281-%281-%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7Ban%7D%29%5E%7B%5Clog%20n%7D%29) tells me that the limit is $1$, but I didn't manage to obtain it by pencil and paper.

Comment: You might try to emulate [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/208886/6179).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use Taylor expansions liberally (when it makes sense to):
$$\left(1-\frac{1}{an}\right)^{\log n}=\exp\left[\log n\cdot\log\left(1-\frac{1}{an}\right)\right]\approx\exp\left[-\frac{\log n}{an}\right]\approx1-\frac{\log n}{an}$$